# Creating file directory to external storage

Tags: android, file, android-external-storage

Good Morning,

I am trying to create file directory to external storage by using below code:

```
File noteDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Notes");
        noteDirectory.mkdirs()
```

My question is what happens if noteDirectory already exists on user's device?

Comment: you can check for directory if it already exits or not "noteDirectory.exists()"

Comment: You should only call mkdirs() if the directory not exists. Use exists() for it. If you use mkdirs() then check the return value as it might fail to create the directory. If so display a toast and return. Do not continue with the code then.

Answer (score 3):

Nothing happens, other than `mkdirs()` will return false. It will not crash with an error or anything like that.

BTW, please replace:

```
File noteDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Notes");
```

with:

```
File noteDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Notes");
```

Comment: Thanks. But if it already exists then what should be the best way to handle it..I can't predict the names of directory on user's device. So what should be the best approach while creating directory?

Comment: ok. Ignore this question. I got it by running the code.In case if directory already exist then data will be written to existing directory.